# MySQL SELECT Duplicated rows from OpenCarts DataBase

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates, row

Just playing with OpenCarts DB to see if I can lear something.
If I use the following **SELECT** the result returns duplicated rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
p.product_id AS pid,
p.model AS modelo,
SUBSTRING(p.model,1,25) AS substr_modelo,
p.image AS foto,
p.price AS preco,
pd.name AS nome,
cd.name AS category
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_to_category p2c ON p.product_id = p2c.product_id
LEFT JOIN category_description cd ON p2c.category_id = cd.category_id
WHERE pd.name LIKE _utf8 'laser%' collate utf8_unicode_ci
ORDER BY p.product_id DESC
```

Note that even using **DISTINCT** it is duplicated, but if I add an **GROUP BY p.product_id** it stops duplicating the rows. Is it the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DISTINCT` removes duplicate **entire rows**.

Use `GROUP BY p.product_id` to display one 1 row per product id.

Note: If you group by product_id, if you have multiple product description's, multiple categories, or multiple category description's The query will return a random row for each. Use the [`MIN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) or [`MAX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) functions to retrieve single ID's, or use the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to retrieve all the description.

### Example

```
SELECT
  p.product_id AS pid,
  p.model AS modelo,
  SUBSTRING(p.model,1,25) AS substr_modelo,
  p.image AS foto,
  p.price AS preco,
  GROUP_CONCAT(pd.name) AS nome,
  GROUP_CONCAT(cd.name) AS category
FROM product p
  LEFT JOIN product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
  LEFT JOIN product_to_category p2c ON p.product_id = p2c.product_id
  LEFT JOIN category_description cd ON p2c.category_id = cd.category_id
  WHERE pd.name LIKE _utf8 'laser%' collate utf8_unicode_ci
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY p.product_id DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have to figure it out why it is duplicating. GROUP_CONCAT(), MIN() and MAX() are not what I am looking for. Perhaps the problem is in my joins (almost for sure, knowing that I do not know how to use it correctly yet).

Comment: @tenshimsm Try `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pd.name)`

Comment: Thank you once again, but GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pd.name) eliminates the duplicates and those that are not.